# Enquiry select sql "advanced level"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below and I want to write a query so that it shows me the tickets that have the description of the event "resolve" and also shows the last description of the event that ticket got it and if it does not have a description of the event that is "resolve" it only shows me the last description of the event that the ticket got

```
Ticket Id   EventId     EventDate    EventDescription
1             1        2021-01-06        create
1             2        2021-01-07        resolve
2             3        2021-01-06        create
3             4        2021-01-15        create
1             5        2021-01-09        close
1             6        2021-01-12        Re-open
2             7        2021-01-10        Assign
2             8        2021-01-22        resolve
```

The table below will help you find the result I want

```
Ticket Id   EventId     EventDate    EventDescription
1             2        2021-01-07        resolve
3             4        2021-01-15        create
1             6        2021-01-12        Re-open
2             8        2021-01-22        resolve
```

*I apologize if my question is not clear because my English is poor*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to identify the rows for each TicketId

```
with r as (
    select * , Row_Number() over(partition by ticketid order by eventid desc) rn
    from t
)
select TicketId, EventId, EventDescription
from r
where rn=1 or EventDescription='resolve' 
order by eventid
```

Comment: Thank you really, I learned new things from your code and the answer was correct, but it turns out that there is a redundancy so I have to improve the code so that the code is supposed to test the ticket so if it had the event 'resolved' and the last event added to it was a 'close' showing us Only the event is 'resolved', but if the ticket does not have the 'resolved' event, it shows us the last event, how can we rewrite the code according to these conditions, can you help me rewrite it?